# AngularJS Rest Service returns data, but not showing on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to teach myself building RESTful API's and I am just using angular to try to display what I retrieve.  I can see in the console that my RESTful call works as it is returning data.  However when it is doing the assignment it seems like it all gets lost.

I feel like I am overlooking something simple but I've been staring at it so long now that I have come to seek some help.

Thanks

This is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HR Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="EmployeeCtrl">
    <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="employee in employeeList">
      <td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{employee.lastName}}</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my main.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
   .controller('EmployeeCtrl', function($scope, $resource, employeeService) {
      // employeeService here has nothing
      $scope.employeeList = [employeeService];
    })
    .factory('employeeService', function ($resource) {
        var source = $resource(
            'http://localhost:8060/RESTExample/REST/WebService/Employee');
        var data =source.query({},function(){
          //this log shows the data
        console.log (data);})
        return data;
    });
```

Comment: this is because your employeeService doesn't really return data, though it should return a promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your code should look like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
.controller('EmployeeCtrl', function($scope, $resource, employeeService) {
  // employeeService here has nothing
  //$scope.employeeList = [employeeService]; // incorrect, you're assigning a service into the first element of an array
    employeeService.then(function(success){
        $scope.employeeList = success.data;
    }, function(error){

    });
})
.factory('employeeService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8060/RESTExample/REST/WebService/Employee').get();
```

or use $http

```
.factory('employeeService', function ($http) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8060/RESTExample/REST/WebService/Employee');
```

Comment: I copied the modification you made and I am getting this: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'then'.  I thought of combining your modification with jfadich's and I received the same thing.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  It's now giving me along with the same error an "Error: [$resource:badcfg]" with the link to the restful API.  I'll take what you have given me and see if I can work it out.  Thanks for the time.

Comment: try switching to the $http service @DerekHansen

Comment: @DerekHansen, `"Error: [$resource:badcfg]"`, means you're returning either an array when `$resource` expects an object, or an object when `$resource` expects an array. Please show the full error message to help enlighten everyone.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon  Thanks! That did it.  I'll definitely spend some time so I know the difference.  Just trying to do a proof of concept as I'm going.

Answer (score 1):

Factories should return an object that is used to query data. It shouldn't return data itself.

```
.controller('EmployeeCtrl', function($scope, $resource, employeeService) {
     // employeeService here has nothing
     employeeService.getEmployees().then(function(data){
         $scope.employeeList = data;
     });
})
.factory('employeeService', function ($resource) {
    return {
        getEmployees: function() {
            var source = $resource(
            'http://localhost:8060/RESTExample/REST/WebService/Employee');
            return source.get().$promise;
        }
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, I tried this as well as SoluableNonagon's final response and I am getting a Object doesn't support property or method 'then' as well as a [$resource:badcfg] with the link to my restful API.  I'll investigate that further.  Thanks for the time.

Comment: @DerekHansen, I would agree with this solution, especially this part: `Factories should return an object that is used to query data`. The implementation may differ, but this concept is on the right track.

Comment: @DerekHansen I've updated my answer. Take a look at the return from `getEmployees` it now returns $promise